# Gurobi multiprocessing

Tags: python, optimization, multiprocessing, gurobi

I am trying to implement multiprocessing to run 9 scenarios in parallel. I have a single model for which constraints are changed based on each scenario. I am trying to run these scenarios in parallel in every iterations. I found the following code from Silke Horn. However, I need to run these scenarios iteratively and this code requires defining model for each iterations. Is there another way where I can define a model once before iteration starts and use this for multiprocessing?

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import gurobipy as gp
def solve_model(input_data):
    with gp.Env() as env, gp.Model(env=env) as model:
        # define model
        model.optimize()
        # retrieve data from model
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        pool.map(solve_model, [input_data1, input_data2, input_data3]
```

Answer (score 0):

For a variety of reasons, each process (or thread, in other languages) will need its own Gurobi environment object, along with its own copy of the model. The sample code you posted will do this, though it does create the model fresh for each process, which is a complication.

There are two reasons you may want to reuse the model:

1. To save the model build time
2. To get a warm start when solving the model

For a properly written model, build time (reason 1) is generally small compared to solve time, so this is not common. That said, if data processing is a major issue, then you could preprocess data once and pass the processed data before calling Pool.map. Warm start (reason 2) is more interesting. You could manually specify a warm start, which you could pass using Queues or Pipes, [as described in the Python multiprocessing module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes). Alternately, you could handle both reasons 1 and 2 together, where each call to pool.map solves multiple models in a sequence; essentially, this makes larger parallel "chunks".

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comment. Would this work? I define the model ahead and then create a copy of it inside the function for multiprocessing.

```
import multiprocessing as mp 
import gurobipy as gp 
#define model as mdl 
def solve_model(input_data): 
    with gp.Env() as env, gp.Model(env=env) as model: 
        new_mdl = mdl.copy() 
        new_mdl.optimize() # retrieve data from model 
        if name == 'main': 
        with mp.Pool() as pool: 
        pool.map(solve_model, [input_data1, input_data2, input_data3]
```